# AWS IIS and SSL

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, iis

We currently have an Amazon EC2 instance hosting a web site on iis. I have obtained a URL and created an SSL certificate all from AWS. I added Load Balancing and pointed it to the instance and certificate.

If I use the URL I requested from AWS, it goes to the hosted site, only it shows the ec2.ipaddress.us-west..., not the URL I requested The site shows up as unsecure.

Can someone point me in the direction for guidence?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you obtained a URL from AWS? Do you mean you registered a domain name? Why are you load balancing a single server? Typically the SSL certificate would be applied on the load balancer.

Comment: Did you point the domain name at the load balancer? If you give us the domain we can check that you did it correctly.

Comment: Certs from amazon can only be used on amazon services such as cloudfront and ELBs.

Comment: yes we registered the URL with AWS. The only info I have come across to make this happen says it can only be done using one of the other AWS services.  This is where I drift off the trail. I am a bit confused on how to proceed at this point.

Comment: Look, "registered the URL with AWS" could mean half a dozen different things. Registered with what? As I said, giving us the domain name would be helpful so we can take a look at the DNS etc.

Comment: the url is orbitalpipeline.cloud

Comment: So, for starters, `orbitalpipeline.cloud` has no DNS records. `www.orbitalpipeline.cloud` does, but that's a separate FQDN as far as DNS is concerned. You should fix that.

Comment: Second, `www.orbitalpipeline.cloud` is pointed directly an an EC2 instance (ec2-35-162-169-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com). AWS's certificates can only be used with an ELB or a CloudFront distribution, hence the invalid certificate.

Comment: Is the ELB different than the Load Balancer? I don't See "Elastic Load Balancer", just "Load Balancer" in the AWS Services window. Since it is only one server, is Cloudfront the best service to use in this case?

Comment: If you're only going to use one server, it doesn't really make sense to pay for a load balancer. Yes, I'd probably use CloudFront in that case. Alternatively, you could just use the instance and provision a non-AWS SSL certificate, probably from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: We actually tried that at first. We got a cert from GoDaddy for our original URL which is very similar to the .cloud one. Since I am such a newb with AWS, I couldn't figure out how to make that happen. Then tried using a URL(.cloud) we registered with AWS and couldn't figure that out either.  Hence, the reaching out for you guys' help.

Comment: Installing the certificate really has little to do with AWS if you're just installing it directly on the server itself. Any Let's Encrypt tutorial (doesn't have to be AWS specific, just fine one for your particular webserver) should do the trick, and it's free too.